# Thymeleaf access field of class

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a class, called A with multiple fields, and another class called B that has an object of class A.
In the form the th:object is of class B
Then in the html file I want to get the input using thymeleaf for a field in class A in th:field
So normally I would do `th:field="*{field}"`, but the field is not inside class B it is inside class A...so how do i do `th:field="{B.Aobj.field}"` please?
I have tried

Comment: Anyway, I found out a way. If anyone has something better please tell me ! 
So, I create an object A_obj  of class A and an object B_obj of class B in the controller. I then set the A_obj  as attribute for my B_obj. Then I add them both to the Model. And in the page.html  the form will have as object the B_obj. In the inputs I'll call the fields of A_obj  with  th:field="*{A_obj.field}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add A to the model.  You can access attributes of child objects just by adding extra dots `.`.  For example, if your classes look like this:

```
class Directions {
  private int miles;
  private Location source;
  private Location destination;

  // all the getters and setters
}

class Location {
  private String name;
  private String address;
  
  // all the getters and setters
}
```

You can access both `A` and `B`'s attributes by dot-walking.

```
<form th:object="${directions}">
  <!-- properties of a -->
  <input type="text" th:field="*{miles}" />

  <!-- properties of b -->
  <input type="text" th:field="*{source.name}" />
  <input type="text" th:field="*{source.address}" />

  <input type="text" th:field="*{destination.name}" />
  <input type="text" th:field="*{destination.address}" />
</form>
```